# ProGuard - obfuscating SpringBoot 'fat' jar

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, proguard, obfuscation

I have problem with obfuscation using ProGuard plugin in my application.
Let me show my usecase:

1. My application uses libs (given as dependencies from artifactory) that needs to be obfuscated after developing phase (public API of libs needs to be protected agains reverse engineering).

2. My code should stay in form 'as it is' - for logging purposes.

3. I can't get my jar from open directory (eg. jars from folder libs). I have to use libs given from artifactory/m2 and obfuscate them in build process (gradle task).

4. Obfuscated application needs to be placed in 'fat' springboot jar.

Do You think that Proguard could deal with this usecase?

Thank's for any help!

Comment: I think there is some problem in your jar creation process, I have done it in past with maven and seen no issues